# Finding the Minimum Price | Supply, Demand Equation

Tags: economics

Suppose that Kodak supplies its “Instamatic” film cameras according to the equation

Qs = -47,400 + 5,000*PK , where PK is the Kodak camera’s price.

Consumer demand for Kodak’s instamatic cameras is given by the equation

Qd = 33,600 - 100*PK + 2*PN - 50*LN

where PN is the price of the Nikon = $13,000
LN is the quality of the Nikon = 100

.
.
.

What is the minimum price at which Kodak will sell its instamatic camera?

Comment: I don't really understand what they mean by finding the "minimum price"

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your post. Please also include your thoughts and anything you've tried. If that doesn't amount to much, you should try some more -- other posters will be more amenable to helping you if you do. Also, you may be interested in [Economics.SE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve the following equation: $Qd(PK) = Qs(PK)$

Comment: So finding the equilibrium ?

Comment: Yes, $Qs=Qd$ means equilibrium.